# What constitutes unsalvageble (triage moderation review)

Tags: discussion, triage

I find it strange that you fail moderation review if you answer "should be improved". In this case here:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7910407

should be improved is a perfectly fine answer. The question can easily be improved (add the name of the cipher any maybe the sample values as hex). I think generally the review system should accept "should be improved" as a fair moderation judgement to a "known closed" bait as the risk of false positives is too high. Especially in the triage queue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no way for the community to salvage that question.  Marking it as NI is *actively harmful*, so it is quite correct for you to have failed that audit.

Marking posts that can't actually be improved as "needing improvement" is actively harmful to the system.   It results in pushing posts to the H&I queue for editing by the community *even though the community can't edit it into a good question*.  In fact, so many unsalvageable questions are being pushed into that queue that it is *dramatically* harming the utility of that queue, and causing a lot of people to not use it due to the difficulty in actually finding questions that can be salvaged.

Comment: In that case the review system should actually make clear that "can only be improved by asker" is not a valid option. I was not aware that the consequence is, that somebody else must improve it (which he clearly cant, i would agree).

Comment: I pointed out that problem before the queue even existed.  Sadly, the problem has gone unaddressed for many months now.

Answer (score 11):

Regardless of the merits of the question itself, *it isn't a programming question*. Notice how it doesn't mention *anything* programming-related anywhere in it?

With a bit of work, it might be a good fit for [the Puzzling site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), but for Stack Overflow it's wholly off-topic.